# Problem with apt-get upgrade and dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dependencies

Im trying to upgrade my system but when I execute the command this happens:

```
plex@plex-server:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
[sudo] password for plex:
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree         
Reading state information... Done  
You may want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to fix it.
The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
  libgail-3-0 : Depends: libgtk-3-0 (=3.22.30-1ubuntu4) but 3.22.30-1ubuntu1 is installed
  libgtk-3-bin : Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.22.30-1ubuntu4) but 3.22.30-1ubuntu1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Run 'apt --fix-broken install' without packages (or specify a solution).
```

I have done update before and I've tried autoclean, autoremove, --fix-missing but it still doesn't work.

EDIT
This is what I have in my sources.list file:

```
#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 18.04 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180426)]/ 
bionic main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
# deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main 
restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the 
Ubuntu                                             ## team. Also, please 
note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
# deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
# deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the 
Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as 
to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
# deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it 
includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any 
review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted 
universe multiverse
# deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main 
restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and 
the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main 
restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
```

Comment: Next time please use the code formatting and not the quote, since here all the line breaks are missing. Did you try what it suggests `sudo apt --fix-broken install`? Post its output here please

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at the key part of the error message:

```
Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas: 
  libgail-3-0 : Depende: libgtk-3-0 (=3.22.30-1ubuntu4) pero 3.22.30-1ubuntu1 está instalado
  libgtk-3-bin : Depende: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.22.30-1ubuntu4) pero 3.22.30-1ubuntu1 está instalado
```

It says that you are trying to upgrade newer packages with older versions. Read it again, playing close attention to the difference between the version numbers.

Let's use a handy apt tool to see which repository these packages came from:

```
$ apt cache madison libgtk-3-bin
libgtk-3-bin | 3.22.30-1ubuntu1 | http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
libgtk-3-bin | 3.22.30-1ubuntu4 | http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
```

Oh look, BOTH packages are listed. One is in bionic, the other in bionic-updates.

So the system is complaining that it NEEDS the version from bionic-updates, but cannot install it.

Time to look at your sources in your Software & Updates control panel (or in /etc/apt/sources.list). Ensure that the repo for bionic-updates is present and enabled.

Comment: This is what I have in my sources.list. If I'm not wrong, bionic-updates should be enabled (I've deleted comented lines). 
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

Comment: Please add new information to your original question, formatted properly, instead of burying it in comments.

Comment: Did you remember to run `sudo apt- update` before `upgrade`? If so, did you get any `update` errors?

Comment: Yes I updated before with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

First try this command:

```
apt --fix-broken install
```

And then:

```
sudo apt update
```